# Finding the perfect fit for a serialized object written to a MemoryMappedFile

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

Currently, I use the code below to find a fit for a serialized object in a `MemoryMappedFile`.

Basically, I increase the size of the `MemoryMappedFile` until the `NotSupportedException` (cannot extend length of stream) is not thrown anymore.

```
MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(blobName, this.size);
bool serializeOk = false;

while (!serializeOk)
{
    try
    {
        using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
        } 

        serializeOk = true;
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException)
    {
        mmf.Dispose();
        this.size *= 2;
        mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(blobName, this.sizeMemMapFile);
    }
}
```

**Q.** Can somebody come up with a solution which provides a better fit and is more efficient?

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: Also your question is not a question.

Comment: @gunr2171 The provided code is a demo for what I'm looking for rather than an acceptable solution.

Comment: Might still be a hack, but wouldn't be as expensive: Serialize the object twice, the first time just counting how many bytes are written. Then size the MMF and write to it. To do this, create a dummy Stream implementation that just counts how many bytes are written to it and throws the data away.

Comment: @mikez Since the objects are heavy I would like to have a solution, which doesn't require serializing the same object multiple times.

Comment: How big can it be? You already have it in memory and you are writing to a non-persisted MMF.

Comment: @mikez Actually, it's a network of objects and its serialized size is about 2MB. (I use the MMF for IPC, and I need to traffic some of them.)

Comment: Have you considered using a named pipe? They are backed by MMF so should have performance that is very close to raw MMF but are accessed like streams.